# Как с помощью Jquery обновлять содержимое value selected option?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Ребят ве сделал осталось штрихи конечные ...Пытаюсь обнавить значение optiona таким методом

```
$('#select option:eq(3)').val("new values")
```

но ничего не происходит ...

Comment: поясните, что именно вы хотите сделать. А то в заголовке вопроса присутствуют слова `selected`, а в самом вопросе этого нет. Данный код потенциально должен 4му дочернему элементу `option` для элемента с идентификатором `#select` изменить значение `value`.

Comment: я знаю но не меняет

Comment: дак и как это связано с `selected`? в ответе ниже вон все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде все правильно написали, у меня ваш код работает. Может вам еще и текст опции менять?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#select option:eq(3)').val("new values");
   $('#select option:eq(3)').html("new values");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = 'select'>
  <option value = '1'>1</option>
  <option value = '2'>2</option>
  <option value = '3'>3</option>
  <option value = '4'>4</option>
  <option value = '5'>5</option>
</select>
```